# How the size of SQL server be allocated for each database in SQL server 2012?

Tags: sql-server, memory-management, sql-server-2012

> I am currently using SQL server having allocated size of 16GB and i
>   have 3 databases in the SQL server, now my question is how will the
>   size be allocated for each database?

Comment: Since the question was unclear weither the size allocated was about memory or file sizes, I posted both answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initial file size of a Database can be specified at Database creation.

```
CREATE DATABASE [MyDB]
ON PRIMARY (Name = N'MyDB', FILENAME = N'C:\MyDB.mdf', SIZE = 5120KB, FILEGROWTH = 1024KB)
LOG ON (NAME = N'MyDB_log', FILENAME = N'C:\MyDB_log.ldf', SIZE = 1024KB, FILEGROWTH = 10%)
```

Then when the file data reaches its capacity you have two options.
Either the file is in autogrowth, and the file will automatically grow of the FILEGROWTH size (percentage or fixed bytes).
Or if not, the database will just ROLLBACK the transaction and emit an error.

Then afterwards, you can check sizes of your files by using the following requests.
The request works since SQL Server 2005.
If you need a request under SQL 2005, I have one if required.

This one for datafiles :

```
SELECT
    D.name,
    (SUM(F.size)*8)/1024 AS FileSize
FROM sys.master_files F
INNER JOIN sys.databases D
ON D.database_id = F.database_id
WHERE F.type_desc = 'ROWS'
GROUP BY D.database_id, D.name
ORDER BY D.database_id
```

This one for logfiles :

```
SELECT
    D.name,
    (SUM(F.size)*8)/1024 AS FileSize
FROM sys.master_files F
INNER JOIN sys.databases D
ON D.database_id = F.database_id
WHERE F.type_desc = 'LOG'
GROUP BY D.database_id, D.name
ORDER BY D.database_id
```

References :
[CREATE DATABASE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms176061.aspx)
[DATA FILE Full](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337441.aspx)
[LOG FILE Full](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337278.aspx)

PS :
[Here a little note on how to choose weither autogrow or not.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23305/sql-server-best-practices-for-growing-database-files)

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server allocates memory paging according to the requests passed.

`The I/O from an instance of the SQL Server Database Engine includes logical and physical reads. A logical read occurs every time the Database Engine requests a page from the buffer cache. If the page is not currently in the buffer cache, a physical read first copies the page from disk into the cache.`

`The instance then continues to acquire memory as needed to support the workload. As more users connect and run queries, SQL Server acquires the additional physical memory on demand.`

For example, you make a specific SELECT once after startup, the pages read are loaded in memory.
If you do the same SELECT just after the first one, the pages will be directly read from memory.

Then pages are kept in memory as long as possible, and when new pages need to be loaded into memory if there is no memory available anymore some clean pages may be released from memory.

`A SQL Server instance continues to acquire physical memory until it either reaches its max server memory allocation target or Windows indicates there is no longer an excess of free memory; it frees memory when it has more than the min server memory setting, and Windows indicates that there is a shortage of free memory.`

A clean page is a page that is up to date with data-file datas.
Opposed to a dirty page, which is a page loaded in memory, modified and not commited yet.

To make short : The size of memory required may reach the total size of all databases in your instance if you need to address all data at the same time.
If pagelife in memory is short your performances will decrease.
You can monitor PageLife with a Perfmon for example or with the built-in DataCollector.

You can also manage the instance settings to allocate min/max memory size. According to other ressources required for the system and other processes.

References :
[Writing Pages](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337560(v=sql.105).aspx)
[Reading Pages](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191475(v=sql.105).aspx)
[Dynamic Memory Management](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178145(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: so what you say is that there is no size allocated to a database during creation. right? @Hybris95

Comment: Are you talking about memory usage or file size ? This is unclear

Comment: i am talking about size @Hybris95